# Update a forked local branch to upstream/master

Tags: git

I am using a fork of a fork. I will denote these fork1 and fork2. I work on fork2.

project(upstream) --> fork1 --> fork2(origin) --> local

Parenthesis denote the role i.e., project acts as the upstream repo, fork2 is the origin repo, and local is the local repo. A lot of commits have gone into `upstream`. I have made many changes to a branch in local which I will call `local/branch_new` (I do not use `local/master`). I would like to update `local/branch_new` to that of `upstream/master` while retaining all of my local changes (they will not conflict, they are entirely new, added files, although they depend on files which do have changes to them in the upstream version). Then I will push `local/branch_new` to `origin(fork2)` and make a `pull request` to `upstream/master`.

Steps I believe I need to do

1. set `project` officially as `upstream`. Currently, when I `git pull`, it believes `origin/branch_old` is the upstream. I am on a different branch and don't want it associated with `origin/branch_old`.
2. use `git pull` to update my local branch or possibly, update `local/master`, and then update `local/branch_new`?
3. `git push` from `local/branch_new` to form a new `origin/branch_new`. This part should be trivial.
4. make PR to project/master. This part should be trivial.

I am stuck on parts 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

How I will do:

Set the upstream of branch_new to origin:

`git branch -u origin/branch_new`

Update the local information about upstream:

`git fetch upstream`

When on `branch_new`, stash my local change:

`git stash`

add some change to commit with `git add -p`, then commit `git commit` and finally push `git push`

rebase my local branch:

`git rebase upstream/master`

Then apply my stashed modification:

`git stash apply`

Comment: I am a little confused because origin is not the upstream and origin does not already contain the branch_new. I have a local branch and that is all. Other branches have been pushed to origin, so there exists origin/other_branches. Can I just rebase my local branch on top of the upstream?

Comment: using upstream as the name of a specific upstream is confusing, your issue is with your naming of upstream. The given command will create the branc `branch_new` when you will push it into the repository `origin`